# Installing 'modular-scale' using Grunt require without compass config.rb

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compass, modular-scale

I'm trying to install 'modular-scale' (https://github.com/Team-Sass/modular-scale) via my Gruntfile but I can't get it to work.

Note that I don't use a config.rb, I want to require the plugin using Grunt via grunt-contrib-compass.

I thought it was as simple as adding this to my Gruntfile (after the `grunt.initConfig({` etc):

```
compass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      require: ['modular-scale'], // This line here
      sassDir: 'setup',
      cssDir: 'css'
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  css: {
    files: '**/*.scss',
    tasks: ['compass']
  }
}
```

The watch task is absolutely fine.  The problem is that if I use one of the SASS variables that are part of the 'modular-scale' plugin, I'll get an error thrown up, suggesting that the 'modular-scale' isn't actually being required.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need Compass or a config.rb file to use modular-scale.